# how to design a full-text indexing system?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, information-retrieval

**Lucene** is a great open source indexng library, my problem is not about how to use this kind of indexing tool, but to learn and understand how they are designed.

Maybe I should read the source code of **Lucene**, but I can't seem to find any tutorial about how this great work is done.

So, is there any other way or a book that can help me gain a concrete understanding of how to design such a indexing system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The science behind Lucene is called as Information Retrieval. When you start appreciating the Algorithms and Data Structures behind Information Retrieval, you are all done and Lucene or Sphinx would merely be tools to solve your tasks. The very first thing is you can go through [Inverted Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) Data Structure.

A great book about Information Retrieval Algorithms and Data Structure can be found here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/ This Stanford text is a good resource and a good starting point in coming to know about how Information Retrieval Systems are designed